# GCM registrationId rare characters

Tags: android, notifications, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using in my Android app the class `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService` and its method `onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId)`.

Recently this method has started to get the registrationId value with a rare string at the beginning, like `|ID|1|: dSyzRPhBqSg:`, followed by the right GCM id.

I don't know what is the reason of this. Perhaps it is because I have started to use recently the Firebase SDK.

Any ideas?

Thank you

EDIT: The code of the onRegistered

```
@Override
protected void onRegistered(final Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
}
```

Comment: show your code that prints the id

Comment: added to the question

Comment: what does it print exactly

Comment: Device registered: regId = |ID|1|:fztTopou4pM:APA91bHaCnSO655b5ZfgWZs.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called Canonical ID. In the Firebase documentation says:

> A canonical registration ID is the registration token of the last
>   registration requested by the client app . This is the ID that the
>   server should use when sending messages to the device.
>
> If you try to send a message using an old registration token, GCM will
>   process the request as usual, but it will include the canonical ID in
>   the registration_id field of the response. Make sure to replace the
>   registration token stored in your server with this canonical ID, as
>   eventually the old registration token will stop working.

And the reason for this is the client app triggers multiple registrations for the same device.

Comment: Why don't my canonical IDs have the `|ID|1|:` prefix?